# Filter by scopes in the project tool window?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ 2017.1.2

I defined a scope with the intention to filter files with specific file endings in the project tool window. Yet I don't see a way to make this happen.

How can I filter by scope in the project tool window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the same under 2017.1.2, but in IntelliJ 2018.1.6 you just need to click the `Project` dropdown menu, and select the Scope you want to see.

[image: Screenshot of the "Project" dropdown menu with Scope selection functionality]

PS. I found this [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206931665-How-can-i-hide-filter-certain-files-in-a-project-view-?page=1#community_comment_207093809).

Comment: I had defined a scope but somehow failed to see it in the `Project` drop down menu. Maybe because in my version of IntelliJ they don't have the icons besides the scope.